# perl print formatting question

Tags: perl, formatting

I want to display a table in perl, the rows and column names for which will be of variable length. I want the columns to be neatly aligned. The problem is the row and column heading are of variable length, so the alignment shifts off for different files.

Here is the code I am using to format :

```
print "\n              ";
foreach (keys(%senseToSenseCountHash))
{
 printf "%15s",$_;
}
print "\n";
print "------------------------------------------------------------\n";

my $space = "---";

foreach my $realSense (keys(%actualSenseToWronglyDisambiguatedSense))
{ 
 printf "%s",$realSense; 

        foreach (keys(%senseToSenseCountHash))
 {
   if(exists($actualSenseToWronglyDisambiguatedSense{$realSense}[0]{$_}))
   {
  printf "%15s",$actualSenseToWronglyDisambiguatedSense{$realSense}[0]{$_};
   }
   else
   {
  printf "%15s",$space;
   }
 }
 print "\n";
}
```

The outputs I get are as follows (for different files that I have to test on) :

```
                    Microsoft            IBM
------------------------------------------------------------
Microsoft            896            120
IBM             66            661



                     SERVE12         SERVE2         SERVE6        SERVE10
------------------------------------------------------------
SERVE12            319             32             19              8
SERVE2             44            159             39             25
SERVE6             22              9            102              1
SERVE10             14             16             12            494



                       HARD3          HARD2          HARD1
------------------------------------------------------------
HARD3             68              7             27
HARD2              6             60             90
HARD1             37             69            937
```

I want to make this output aligned regardless of the row and column name. Can anyone please help?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Look at [Perl6::Form](http://search.cpan.org/~dconway/Perl6-Form-0.04/Form.pm), or the deprecated (in 'Perl Best Practices') Perl [form](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html) mechanism.  Interestingly, Perl6::Form is not listed at CPAN under Perl6; I'm not sure of the significance of that.

Comment: You can use the formline function without using a format declaration, like the swrite function in the perlform page, but localizing $^A

Comment: @Jonathan: Please do not tell people that things are deprecated unless it’s something controlled by the `deprecated` lexical warnings category! In particular, *PLEASE*   ̲D̲O̲ ̲N̲O̲T̲ ̲U̲S̲E̲  *Perl Best Practices* to bludgeon people into homogeneity and silliness. That is not what the book was written for! Damian Conway himself says: **“So many people forget that PBP was —at its heart — a plea for code to be written in *any* consistent style, consciously and rationally chosen to meet one’s own needs.”**

Comment: @Jonathan: That said, I second your recommendation to use Perl6::Form.

Comment: @tchrist: I am not convinced that my comment was bludgeoning anybody with anything.  I was simply pointing out that the Perl form mechanism also exists, but the PBP book does recommend against using them for a variety of reasons (which are sound, but which I'm not going to explain here).  Basically, just pointing out that there are demerits (as well as some merits) to the traditional form mechanism.

Comment: No, PBP mistakenly claims that you have to use global variables in forms. This is not true, and hasn't been true for a very, very, very long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, pasting it here in case any one wants to use it.

```
printf "%10s %-2s",'----------','|';

foreach(keys(%senseToSenseCountHash))
{
    printf "%s",'----------------';
}
print "\n";

printf "%10s %-2s",'          ','|';

foreach(keys(%senseToSenseCountHash))
{
    printf "%-14s",$_;
}
print "\n";

printf "%10s %-2s",'----------','|';

foreach(keys(%senseToSenseCountHash))
{
    printf "%s",'----------------';
}
print "\n";

foreach my $key (sort { $senseToSenseCountHash{$b} <=> 
                              $senseToSenseCountHash{$a} } keys %senseToSenseCountHash )
{
    $maxSense = $senseToSenseCountHash{$key};
    last;   
}

my $space = "---";

foreach my $realSense (keys(%actualSenseToWronglyDisambiguatedSense))
{

    printf "%-10s %-2s",$realSense,'|'; 
        foreach (keys(%senseToSenseCountHash))
    {
        if(exists($actualSenseToWronglyDisambiguatedSense{$realSense}[0]{$_}))
        {
            printf "%-15s",$actualSenseToWronglyDisambiguatedSense{$realSense}[0]{$_};
        }
        else
        {
            printf "%-15s",$space;
        }
    }
    print "\n";
}

printf "%10s %-2s",'----------','|';

foreach(keys(%senseToSenseCountHash))
{
    printf "%s",'----------------';
}
print "\n";
```

Output :

```
---------- | ------------------------------------------------
           | HARD3         HARD2         HARD1         
---------- | ------------------------------------------------
HARD3      | 68             7              27             
HARD2      | 6              60             90             
HARD1      | 37             69             937            
---------- | ------------------------------------------------


---------- | ----------------------------------------------------------------
           | SERVE12       SERVE2        SERVE6        SERVE10       
---------- | ----------------------------------------------------------------
SERVE12    | 319            32             19             8              
SERVE2     | 44             159            39             25             
SERVE6     | 22             9              102            1              
SERVE10    | 14             16             12             494            
---------- | ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
printf "%s",$realSense;
```

has no specific width, and is throwing off the alignment.

Comment: Even if I add alignment to it. It doesn't help too much.